# How to start container in python?

Tags: python, docker

I am trying to start container in python, so that I am able to see it after 'docker ps'.
I have used

> client.container.run(image_name, detach=True)

It is returning container id properly but it's state is 'Exited' only. How it will be 'Up' or 'running', so that I can see it in 'docker ps' command output?

Comment: *What* container? Does it default to a long running process? Does it start and stay up when started *outside* Python?

Comment: `Exited` means that the container ran and completed successfully. Check the log to find details of the run.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in the dockerfile is nothing defined that should be executed when the container is started. Am I right?

Try this:

```
client.container.run(image_name, command="sleep 6000", detach=True)
```

Then your docker container should be listed in "docker ps"

Comment: Running artificial commands to keep a container from exiting isn't really a best practice.  Run the actual command you want the container to run, and if that's exiting, understand why.

Comment: @DavidMaze This is an example of a question that has no information about what the container should be running. How am I supposed to give an example of what the container should run if the OP doesn´t mention anything?
I even mentioned that there is probably nothing defined that should be executed.